# Device tree writing for raspberry pi

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, driver, kernel-module, boot

I'm looking for any appropriate solution for **Device tree writing in raspberry pi**

I went through:

1. basic device driver module loading and unloading
2. adding a kernel module in kernel source tree so that it can loaded automatically just like predefined kernel modules.

But now i have doubt about **how one can write device tree** in raspberry-pi for binding a particular driver or module at the booting time phase?

I researched lots of available resources within the Internet but unfortunately I could not find any precise solution that suits my need.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your question? Writing a device tree is not needed for RPi as it's already available.

Comment: yes,i need to add one node in device tree and according to that, driver which is written by me is need to be loaded at a boot time. in short i want to write a dummy node in device tree and dummy driver for raspberry pi which is loaded at boot time.

Comment: The binding between a DT node and a device driver is by the `compatible` property.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840267/driver-code-in-kernel-module-doesnt-execute

Comment: but where should i add this DT node ? i'm using raspberry pi and interested to write demo platform driver.

Answer (score 0):

So you just need to add a node in your device tree and set the "compatible" property point to your driver. Check below link for reference.

https://github.com/saiyamd/skeleton-dt-binding/blob/master/skeleton.c

Comment: in which file i need to add this ? i'm using raspberry pi 2 model b. thanks for your help !