# Device Tree Vs .Config file | Are they different?

Tags: linux-kernel, config, linux-device-driver, device-tree

I read that [Linux device tree](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/devicetree/usage-model.html) as a datastructure defining the hardware of the device (components present such as I2C, USB etc)

Question: How is this different then .config file that tells make-file of the device drivers to be compiled for kernel i.e what modules in the device are present?

Comment: Drivers compiled into the kernel have nothing to do with devices actually present on the system.  Of course, both must be present to have a working device.

Comment: Device Tree is platform description of the **physical devices** present on it. Configuration file is about **device drivers** that are present in the software and may drive the devices on the platform the software is run on.

Comment: @0andriy i still dont understand the motivation to distinguish between the two. What value device tree bring that device drivers dont bring?

Comment: @stark i dont understand why drlvers compiled into the kernel have nothing to do with devices present on the system. Without the drivers devices have no meaning..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Device Tree Vs .Config file | Are they different?

Yes, they are different, and serve different purposes at different times.

The **.config** file is an integral component of the kernel's build procedure.
The **.config** file is data to control the building of the kernel, that is, its contents is used by makefiles.
A **.config** file could be customized to build a kernel specifically for just one specific version of a SBC.
Or the **.config** file could specify a kernel with a plethora of features, subsystems, and drivers for a variety of capabilities and support families of SBCs.  Such a kernel image could be booted by any compatible board.

---

A **.config** file consists of lines of configuration symbols, e.g. `CONFIG_xxx=...`.
Assignments of strings or numeric constants are rare, but do exist, e.g. `CONFIG_LOCALVERSION="my_version"` and `CONFIG_INIT_ENV_ARG_LIMIT=32`.
Typically the assignment is `y` to affirm that the configuration item is enabled.
A configuration item that is disabled is not asigned `n`, but rather commented out, e.g. `# CONFIG_xxx is not set`.
A configuration item that is "tristate" can be assigned `m` to affirm that the configuration item is enabled but built as a loadable module (rather than statically linked, aka built-in).

Note that although kernel source code may contain preprocessor directives (e.g. **#ifdef** for conditional compilation) utilizing CONFIG_xxx symbols  that appear identical to the **.config** symbols, these symbols are not equivalent.
Kernel source code does not read or use the **.config** file.
Rather the **.config** file is converted into a C header file of preprocessor statements with a **#define** for each enabled CONFIG_xxx line, and stored in **include/generated/autoconf.h** (the exact path has changed for older versions).
It is the **autoconf.h** file that defines the CONFIG_xxx symbols used in kernel source code.
Note that a tristate configuration item that is assigned `m` in the **.config** becomes `#define CONFIG_xxx_MODULE 1` in the **autoconf.h** file, rather than just `#define CONFIG_xxx 1`.

---

Device Tree is used by only a handful of CPU architectures in the Linux kernel.
The Device Tree (blob) is data to inform the *executing* kernel of its hardware environment (i.e. the target board).  It also informs the kernel which device drivers to initialize (using the `compatible` property string).
Regardless of how many device drivers are statically linked into the kernel or available as loadable modules, a device driver is only initialized if there is a DT device node that references that device driver (e.g. see [Driver code in kernel module doesn't execute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840267/driver-code-in-kernel-module-doesnt-execute)).
(The exception to that are buses that have self-identifying devices such as USB and PCI/PCIe, which have different procedures for initializing their device drivers.)

---

The Device Tree goes through several transformations before it is utilized by an executing kernel.
The DT source file(s) for a specific board exist as one **.dts** and optional **.dtsi** (included) files that are compiled into a **.dtb** file, aka DT blob.
It is the DT blob that is loaded with the kernel during boot, and then converted from its "flat" organization into a tree structure in kernel memory.
Kernel routines, e.g. device drivers, access the DT using methods provided by **of_***() routines (where the "of" is for Open Foundation).

Comment: Quite nice explanation! I am slightly confused perhaps of the wording isnt `Or the .config file could specify a kernel with a plethora of features, subsystems, and drivers for a variety of capabilities and support families of SBCs.` and .`Regardless of how many device drivers are statically linked into the kernel or available as loadable modules, a device driver is only initialized if there is a DT device node that references that device driver.` pretty much the same thing? I can manually choose devices to be initialized by issuing .`make menuconfig` command. I shall read the answer again.

Comment: @BiologyEnthusiast -- *"I can manually choose devices to be initialized by issuing .`make menuconfig` command"* -- No, that will only control what is built.  Which drivers are *initialized* is determined by the board's DT.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840267/driver-code-in-kernel-module-doesnt-execute   A DT will only have nodes for devices that actually exist on the board (which should be a subset of the drivers built)! The two sentences you quote are not the same, but are complementary.

Comment: makes soo much sense! I thought what is built is also what is initialized! The sentence `which should be a subset of the drivers built` helped me understand it! Thanks!