# Device node and device driver binding

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

If we have a device node for a device in the device tree and the corresponding driver will load into kernel as a module using insmod after embedded device boots up then the driver can access the device node entries using the device tree APIs(say of_get_property ...)? I mean the device node of a device tree and the corresponding driver binding will happen only at boot time?

Comment: Yes. No. (If you don't understand the answers, then ask better questions.) Why are you so skeptical of this functionality? If this was broken, then wouldn't there be many reports of inoperative drivers? You did try to search the web for a possible answer before you posting, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Driver code in kernel module doesn't execute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840267/driver-code-in-kernel-module-doesnt-execute)