# Linux init module at boot up and device tree

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-tree

I'd like to understand something.  I did a custom module driver.

```c
static struct platform_driver mymodule_of_driver = {

    .driver = {
            .name = MY_MODULE_NAME,
            .owner = THIS_MODULE,
            .of_match_table = my_module_of_match,
    },

    .probe = my_module_of_probe,
    .remove = my_module_of_remove,
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Initialize the driver
//
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// device driver init
static int __init my_module_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_CRIT "my-module : init ... we are inside the kernel!\n");

    platform_driver_register( &mymodule_of_driver);

    return 0;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Exit the driver
//
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
static void __exit my_module_exit(void)
{
    platform_driver_unregister( &mymodule_of_driver);

    printk(KERN_CRIT "my-module : exit ... bye bye!\n");

    return 0;
}

module_init(my_module_init);
module_exit(my_module_exit);
```

So, I think my_module_init should be located in the .initcall section. To be confirmed.

In the device tree, for a test, I removed the node for this device and as expected, I don't see at boot up this loaded driver.

I don't understand how kernel knows that my_module_init() function should not be called?  This function is placed in the .init section, so do_initcalls() should call my init function in driver also? But it's not the case because I put printk() and the message is not output.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Driver code in kernel module doesn't execute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840267/driver-code-in-kernel-module-doesnt-execute). The Device Tree is supposed to describe the system hardware. If you remove/disable a piece of hardware (and delete its DT node), then why would the kernel need to probe/init a driver for such missing hardware?